# How does Istio "intercept" traffic for other containers?

Tags: istio

The docs state that Envoy proxies "...mediate and control all network communication between microservices": https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/

How does that work? When I want my program to make connection to an arbitrary hostname, say, "google.com" or "something.default.svc.cluster.local", I'll make two OS calls: `gethostbyname` and `connect`.  How would Envoy, running in another container, "intercept" this? How will it know when I'm accessing "google.com" or a k8s service?

If there is an online doc that explains it, I'd appreciate a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Istio has an Init Container which redirects traffic from/to the application container to the sidecar using iptables. [This article from Istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/data-plane-setup/) explains it.

There is also an alternative [using CNI](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/cni/) instead of the Init container.

Comment: Thank you, just a little nitpick - the first link is to the blog, not Istio's documentation.